# Kotlin reflection - getting all field names of a Class

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

How can I get a list of a Kotlin data class it's `declaredFields`? Like Java's `getDeclaredFields()`

And if this is possible is it also possible to filter for `public` and `private` fields? (Like Java's `Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())`)

Comment: Are you interested in fields (i.e. raw java classes) or properties (i.e. javabeans or Kotlin classes)?  Are you dealing only with Kotlin classes or also Java classes?

Comment: only Kotlin classes but @hotkey 's solution worked for my particular problem

Comment: "_there is no documentation about this call_" -- links for that documentation are below.

Comment: I know, saw it after, I couldn't find it at first/didn't know what to search for so I missed that documentation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably what you want is to get properties of a class, not fields. This can be done as follows:

```
MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties
```

Getting fields is also possible through Java reflection:

```
MyClass::class.java.declaredFields
```

But fields are rather an implementation detail in Kotlin, because some properties might have no [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields).

---

As to the visibility, for properties you can check the getter visibility modifiers:

```
val p = MyClass::class.declaredMemberProperties.first()
val modifiers = p.javaGetter?.modifiers
```

Note: it's `null` in case of a simple `private val` or [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) usage. Then you can inspect `p.javaField` instead.

Then, if `modifiers` is not `null`, just check it with `Modifier.isPrivate(...)`.

Properties in Kotlin can have [separate visibility modifiers for getter and setter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters), but a setter access cannot be more permissive than that of the getter, which is effectively the property visibility.

Comment: and is it possible to create an MyClass object, and set these `declaredFields` (using the Java reflection) with the `Field.name`?

Comment: In case java class has a field is `public static final String`, can I get its string value?

Comment: `import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties` to get it working in case the IDE wouldn't suggest this.

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed documentation available for Kotlin reflection: [an overall summary of reflection](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) and the [API docs](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/index.html) including for the [KClass.members](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/members.html) function.  You can also jump to the declaration of that method and you will see it is documented in the source code as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MyClass::class.java.declaredFields` or it's instance: `myObject::class.java.declaredFields`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check which members are a subclass of `KProperty1<*,*>`.

```kotlin
MyClass::class.members.filter{
  when(it){
    is KProperty1<*,*> -> true
    else -> false
  }
}.map{ it as KProperty<MyClass,*> }
```

Why `KProperty1`? As said in the documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property/),
`KProperty0` is for static properties (as those defined in the root of a packate). `KProperty2` is for extension properties and `KProperty1` is for fields.

It can be mixed with Java reflection if you want only declared properties.