# Filter on list by a generic column in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Kotlin and trying to filter on a generic class, therefore I don't actually have the name to go after the it.__
Is there a way of filtering on a generic column name ?

```
override fun getData(
    tableName: String,
    searchTerm: String?,
    columnName: String?
): List<BaseEntity> {
    for (clazz in getAllEntityClasses()) {
        if (clazz.simpleName == tableName) {
            val list = getList()
            return list.filter{it.GENERIC_COLUMNAME == searchTerm} as List<BaseEntity>
                }
            
            }
    
    return listOf()
}
```

Comment: Hi Sharone, please describe what is the return type of "getList()",and what/how is the class you'd like to use whent typing "it.___".

Comment: Thanks, getList() returns a list of List<BaseEntity>, which is what I would like to return. it.__ is a string

Comment: Is GENERIC_COLUMNAME a field of BaseEntity? You should be able to use any field of BaseEntity there, as "it" is of type BaseEntity. Please provide the definition of BaseEntity in the question as well, so we can better help you.

Comment: No, I was just noting where the generic column should come in. BaseEntity is our base class which all entities extend. So the column is in the child class, not in BaseEntity per se.

Comment: so for instance I have a Car entity that extends BaseEntity and I want to filter on 'model' field == "bimba".
model field is not in every other entity.

Comment: columnName is passed as a parameter

Comment: I think this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589780/kotlin-reflection-getting-all-field-names-of-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to filter the list based on the value of a field of the objects in the list. If the column name is the same as the field name then you can do something like this:

```
override fun getData(
    tableName: String,
    searchTerm: String?,
    columnName: String?
): List<BaseEntity> {
    for (clazz in getAllEntityClasses()) {
        if (clazz.simpleName == tableName) {
            val list = getList()
            val field = clazz.getDeclaredField(columnName)
            field.isAccessible = true
            return list.filter{field.get(it) == searchTerm} as List<BaseEntity>                    
        }
    }
    return listOf()
}
```

Note that it is necessary to make the field accessible otherwise private fields will throw an error.